# Get number of records returned by the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, rowcount

I have a stored procedure which does a custom paging by page size 10 and it goes through a table called `Users`. Now I would like to make the stored procedure to also return the number of total records which were returned by the stored procedure, but not just the page size which is 10.

Here is the procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zsp_GetUsersAdministratorPanel]
    (@StartRowIndex INT,
     @MaxRows INT,
     @OrderByField NVARCHAR(200),
     @Asc BIT,
     @SearchValue NVARCHAR(200) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(UserId int,
                              FirstName nvarchar(400),
                              LastName nvarchar(400),
                              Email nvarchar(200)
                             )  

    DECLARE @WhereQuery nvarchar(max)

    SET @WhereQuery = ' WHERE '

    IF LEN(@SearchValue) > 0
        BEGIN
                SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery +
                  'FirstName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' LastName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' Email like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%'''
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
    set @WhereQuery = ' '
    END
    DECLARE @OrderQuery nvarchar(max)

    IF LEN(@OrderByField) > 0
        BEGIN
            IF @OrderByField = 'Email'
                SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY Email ' +
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC ' END
            ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'FirstName'
                SET @OrderQuery =
                    ' ORDER BY FirstName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC '  END
            ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'LastName'  
                SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY LastName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC '  END     

        END 

    DECLARE @Query  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Query = 'select UserId, 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Email,
                @@ROWCOUNT as TotalRows
            from 
            (


                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('+ @OrderQuery +')
                    AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
                        [t0].[UserId], [t0].[FirstName], 
                        [t0].[LastName], 
                        [t0].[Email]
                        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]' +
                        @WhereQuery +
            ') AS [t1]' +
                 + ' WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 
                    @StartRowIndex AND @MaxRows' + @OrderQuery

    PRINT @Query

    INSERT INTO @UsersTable EXEC sp_Executesql @Query,
                    N'@OrderQuery nvarchar(max),
                    @StartRowIndex int,@MaxRows int',
                    @OrderQuery=@OrderQuery,
                    @StartRowIndex = @StartRowIndex,
                    @MaxRows = @MaxRows

    SELECT * FROM @UsersTable           

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

How can I achieve this, can someone help me out please?  :)

I'm guessing I have to use `@@RowCount`, but I'm not too sure where?

P.S. Guys, what I mean by this is that I get the results returned by the "Where" statement, and not only the page size??

P.S. also guys if you have any suggestions to improve the execution time of the procedure, please do so :)

Comment: Those where predicates are going to cripple your performance here. You have leading wildcards so any indexes will be ignored. You also might consider using OPTION RECOMPILE here because you really need to get a fresh execution plan each time this runs.

Comment: @SeanLange could you show me a modified version of what you just wrote in form of answer? I would really really appreciate it, I'm quite a newbie with SQL

Comment: I can't really help you with the leading wildcards. You are looking for a value within a larger string. Perhaps the search can be modified? This query is a type of search all query. Gail Shaw has a great article that goes into detail on the topic here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @SeanLange Okay got it, so the wildcards are the issue here and I should somehow find a way to change the search structure ?

Comment: You may need that functionality. If that is the case using full text search could help the performance aspect of this considerably.

Comment: @SeanLange Okay got it thx ^^ Could you please help me out with this issue with rowcount? Daniel and Andromar have given me some hints but we're still not succeeding xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column for the rowcount to your table variable:

```
DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(TotalRows int, UserId int, ...
```

You can modify your generated SQL like:

```
SET @Query = '
    SELECT  TotalRows, UserId, ...
    FROM    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('+ @OrderQuery +') AS RowNum
            ,       COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
            ,       ...
            ) AS t1
    WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN ...
```

Now your procedure will return the total rowcount in the first column.

Comment: hold on I will try this 2nd solution xD

Comment: Ah but theres a trick... The returned value is alwas 10 since I defined page size = 10 xD I don't insert more than 10 records in temp table xD

Comment: So build another temp table in your proc and write to that - then count at the end

Comment: Ah, so you want the overall row count?  You could `set @Query = 'select count(*) over () as cnt, UserId, ...` to your dynamic sql query, and add a `cnt` column to `@UsersTable`

Comment: @DanielMarcus or should I just all found records into the temp, and then do select top 10 count(*) over () as cnt, * FROM UsersTable ?? Will it affect the performance ? ^^

Comment: @Andomar yes yes overall row count for the records found by the "where" statement xD

Comment: while you can ```return @@rowcount``` this is not recommended.  The return value from a stored procedure should indicate success or failure.  Better to use an output variable for that

Comment: @DanielMarcus I'm just worried about the performance if I insert 50000 records into the temp table and then just select 10? Will it affect the performance ? :/

Comment: i would keep the code exactly as is but add a small counter in there that you update with each pass- you can declare a variable then set to zero and update the variable with its current amount plus the rowcount you add in each pass

Comment: @DanielMarcus could you please show me what you mean in form of answer? I'm not exactly too sure :/

Comment: @DanielMarcus is output variable a better solution like user1443098 stated?

Comment: depends what you are trying to do - if you just need the value returned you can select @counter at the end of proc - otherwise yes use output param

Comment: @DanielMarcus I will need the 10 records from the temp table + total records found by the procedure  xd

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zsp_GetUsersAdministratorPanel]
    (@StartRowIndex INT,
     @MaxRows INT,
     @OrderByField NVARCHAR(200),
     @Asc BIT,
     @SearchValue NVARCHAR(200) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @counter int = 0
    DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(UserId int,
                              FirstName nvarchar(400),
                              LastName nvarchar(400),
                              Email nvarchar(200)
                             )  

    DECLARE @WhereQuery nvarchar(max)

    SET @WhereQuery = ' WHERE '

    IF LEN(@SearchValue) > 0
        BEGIN
                SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery +
                  'FirstName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' LastName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' Email like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%'''
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
    set @WhereQuery = ' '
    END
    DECLARE @OrderQuery nvarchar(max)

    IF LEN(@OrderByField) > 0
        BEGIN
            IF @OrderByField = 'Email'
                SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY Email ' +
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC ' END
            ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'FirstName'
                SET @OrderQuery =
                    ' ORDER BY FirstName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC '  END
            ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'LastName'  
                SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY LastName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 
                    THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC '  END     

        END 

    DECLARE @Query  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Query = 'select UserId, 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Email,
                @@ROWCOUNT as TotalRows
            from 
            (


                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('+ @OrderQuery +')
                    AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
                        [t0].[UserId], [t0].[FirstName], 
                        [t0].[LastName], 
                        [t0].[Email]
                        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]' +
                        @WhereQuery +
            ') AS [t1]' +
                 + ' WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 
                    @StartRowIndex AND @MaxRows' + @OrderQuery

    PRINT @Query

    INSERT INTO @UsersTable EXEC sp_Executesql @Query,
                    N'@OrderQuery nvarchar(max),
                    @StartRowIndex int,@MaxRows int',
                    @OrderQuery=@OrderQuery,
                    @StartRowIndex = @StartRowIndex,
                    @MaxRows = @MaxRows

select @counter=@counter+@@rowcount
select @counter

    SELECT * FROM @UsersTable           

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Comment: Hm, hey how would this look like incorporated into the procedure, still nto sure about the "total_rows" part ? xD

Comment: See edited above - you can adjust accordingly wherever you want to add to the counter (insert records)

Comment: Okay got it but I'm getting the error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: okay I modified and added the TotalRows to temp table, but it shows still 10 records? xd It should show 12000 or something ?